# Counting sort in C implemented according to pseudocode but doesn't run properly

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I have implemented counting sort according to its pseudocode ( that's [written on the blackboard in this video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTksRlHZxXg&t=1m34s) ) but for some mysterious reason, it doesn't seem to sort properly.

For the test input: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

It gives: 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 0 0 9

It seems to be a very simple problem but I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
void counting(int * array, int n){

    int *copy, *out, i,j, max, counter;

    copy = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * max);

    out = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * n );

    max = array[0];

    // finds max size
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) if(array[i] > max) max = array[i];

    // zeroes the counting array
    for(i=0;i<max;++i) copy[i] = 0;

    //counts
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) ++copy[array[i]];

    //cumulative sum
    for(i=1;i<max;++i) copy[i] += copy[i-1];

    //sorts
    for(i=n-1;i>=1;--i){
        out[copy[array[i]]] = array[i];
        --copy[array[i]];
    }

    //overwrite original array with sorted output
    for(i=0;i<n;++i) array[i] = out[i];

}
```

Comment: The value of `max` is *indeterminate* (and will seem random) when you use it in the allocation. Execution goes from top to bottom, nothing is done retroactively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the order in which you allocate the array of counters: when you write

```
copy = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * max);
```

the `max` is not set, so its value is undefined. Therefore, the allocation produces undefined behavior, making your program invalid.

You need to move the allocation past the loop that computes `max`. Allocate `max+1` items, because array indexes are zero-based:

```
int max = array[0];
for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    if(array[i] > max)
        max = array[i];
copy = malloc(sizeof(int) * (max+1));
```

You also need to `free` both `copy` and `out` at the end to avoid memory leaks:

```
free(copy);
free(out);
```